# If $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded, then $E$ got no limit points in $\mathbb{R}$. Why?

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen a lot of proofs that when a set is not bounded, called $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, then it got no limit points in $\mathbb{R}$. But I am still not convinced.

I was thinking about this set:

$$N = \left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \bigcup \left\{n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}.$$

Then $N$ is not bounded but $0$ is a limit point of $N$, right? Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The statement is clearly false. In fact it's very easy to devise unbounded sets that contain $\textit{all}$ it's limit points.

Comment: To emphasize, if $E$ is unbounded then there is no guarantee of a limit point of $E$. $E$ may or may not have a limit point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. The statement “when a set is not bounded […] then it got no limit points in $\mathbb R$” is false.

Comment: (+1) Take for example $E = \mathbb R$. It's unbounded and every point is a limit point.

Comment: Oh, thank you, now I see that what I was trying to prove was different than what I needed.

Comment: @Rodrigo I'm glad I could help.